API-sidecar hangs after bad request
Has anyone ran into a issue where the api-sidecar hangs for a very long time ( > 15 secs)?
This is potentially after a bad request: BadRequestError: The address xxx is not a stash address.
We see the node floating around 4Gb of memory consumption but the container has around 16Gb available...
We're doing a health check on the api-sidecar
curl --silent "http://127.0.0.1:18080/node/network" -m 5 to see if it's still available before we restart the process and even after restarting the container, it still has issues for about a hour afterwards.

We added an issue in the sidecar repo about this https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/issues/1486 and we are looking into this by doing memory testing. We will update the issue with our findings and related PRs.
